# Octave not compiling, confused by build error

Tags: octave, ubuntu-14.04, graphicsmagick

I'm a modest user of Linux; but I appear to have hit a wall here when building Octave.

I need to use Octave 4.0.0 on (64-bit) Ubuntu 14.04, and it seems the only option for me (so far) is to build from source (as the repos apparently don't offer anything prebuilt for this version yet). Anyway, I do

**./configure**

**make**

...and then get this:

> /usr/bin/ld: /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a(magick_libGraphicsMagick_la-analyze.o): relocation R_X86_64_32 against `.gomp_critical_user_GM_GetImageDepthCallBack' can not be used when making a shared object; recompile with -fPIC
>   /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a: error adding symbols: Bad value
>   collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status

I figured this was because my graphicsmagick install wasn't build with -fPIC. So I downloaded graphicsmagick and did

> ./configure --with-shared

and built out a new graphicsmagick (make install). Still the same error. So I tried to "force it" by doing the following to graphicsmagick:

> ./configure CCSHARED="-fPIC" CXXFLAGS="-fPIC"

This time I did a search within the generated Makefile and found -fPIC was, indeed, added to the CXXFLAGS. But after making and install the new graphicsmagick, I still get the same error.

This seems like a build chain problem that I've caused. Any thoughts?

Comment: Did you read the `etc/HACKING` file?

Comment: @RafaelMonteiro, yes, I sure did. I ran ./bootstrap and everything. 

Anything?

Comment: @Ben: You shouldn't build libgraphicsmagick in the first place (the location /usr/local/lib/libGraphicsMagick.a shows, that you have compiled it yourself and not via apt-get or atitude). I suggest uninstalling your libgraphicsmagick from /usr/local and install it via apt-get.

Answer (score -1):

Try with:

```
./configure --enable-shared --disable-static
```